# Problem 23 chapter 5 PMA Rudin (point b)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> The function $f$ defined by $$f(x)=\dfrac{x^3+1}{3}$$has three fixed points, say $\alpha, \beta, \gamma,$ where $\alpha\in (-2,-1), \beta\in (0,1), \gamma\in (1,2).$ For arbitrarily chosen $x_1$, define $\{x_n\}$by setting $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$.
>
> (a) If $x_1<\alpha$, prove that $x_n\to -\infty$ as $n\to \infty$.
>
> (b) If $\alpha<x_1<\gamma$, prove that $x_n\to \beta$ as $n\to \infty$.
>
> (c) If $\gamma<x_1$, prove that $x_n\to +\infty$ as $n\to \infty$.

**Proof of b):**

**1.** If $x_1=\beta$ then for all $n$ we have $x_n=\beta$ and hence $x_n\to \beta$ as $n\to \infty$.

**2.** If $x_1\in (\beta,\gamma)$ then it's easy to check by induction that $x_n\in (\beta, \gamma)$ for all $n$. Why?  Suppose $x_n\in (\beta,\gamma)$ then $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)=\dfrac{x_n^3+1}{3}\in \left(\dfrac{\beta^3+1}{3},\dfrac{\gamma^3+1}{3}\right)=(f(\beta),f(\gamma))=(\beta,\gamma).$

2.1. If $x_1\in (\beta,1]$ then by induction $x_n\in (\beta, 1)$ for all $n$.
Considering function $h(x):=f(x)-x$ which increases on $(-\infty,-1)\cup (1,+\infty)$ and decreases on $(-1,1)$. Hence $\{x_n\}$ decreasing and $\beta$ is lower bound. It's easy to prove that $x_n$ converges to $\beta$. Why? Because if $x_n$ converges to some $L>\beta$ then $L$ would be a fourth fixed point of $f$. Contradiction.

2.2. If $x_1\in (1,\gamma)$ then $\exists N_0$ such that $n\geqslant N_0$ we have $x_n\in (\beta,1)$ and here we can use reasoning of 2.1. Why? Let $x_n\in (1,\gamma)$ for all $n$. But $h(x)=f(x)-x$ increases on $(1,\gamma)$. Hence $h(x_n)<h(\gamma)=0$ or $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)<x_n$. We get that sequence $\{x_n\}$ decreases and $1$ is lower bound. Hence $x_n$ converges to some $L$ which would be a fourth fixed point of $f$. Contradiction.

**3.** If $x_1\in (\alpha,\beta)$ here we can use similar reasoning.

I solved point b) and can anyone check my proof please?

Comment: (This is about Point 2.*) I think it might be easier to note that $f(x) < x$ for $x \in (\beta,\gamma)$ and so from Point 2, you have $x_{n+1} \le x_n$ for all $n$ (and $x_n \in [\beta, \gamma)$). So you know that $x_n \downarrow x^*$, and $f(x^*) = x^*$. Hence you must have $x^* = \beta$.

Comment: Note that the fact that $h$ is increasing is less relevant than the fact that $h(x) \le 0$ on $[\beta,\gamma]$.

Comment: @copper.hat, My above edited solution is also true, right?

Comment: Well, not exactly. The fact that $h$ is increasing does not let you conclude that the $x_n$ are decreasing. It is the fact that $h$ is non positive that lets you conclude that. Note that $h(x_n) = x_{n+1}-x_n$, so if $h$ is negative, the sequence is decreasing. The fact that $h$ is increasing does not let you conclude that (it could be positive and increasing).

Comment: @copper.hat, Why? Here is my proof: $h(x)=f(x)-x$ increases on $[1,\gamma]$ and by the way $h(\gamma)=0$ and $h(1)=-1/3<0$. Since $x_n<\gamma$ then $h(x_n)\leqslant h(\gamma)=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(x_n)\leqslant x_n$ $\Rightarrow$ $x_{n+1}\leqslant x_n$. Am I right?

Comment: Well, you are correct, but you are leaving it to the reader to figure out that if $h(\gamma) = 0$ and $h$ is **increasing** on $[1, \gamma]$ that $h(x) \ge 0$ on this interval. I think it is simpler (and you can combine 2.1-2.2) if you use the fact that $h(x) \le 0$ on $[\beta,\gamma]$.

Comment: Click on my name and then profile; look at the bottom line...